# Using an old iphone as camera input for raspberry pi

Tags: networking, camera, ipcam

I have seen some apps on android that seem to be able to stream it's video feed to the raspberry pi as if it was a camera connected to the raspberry pi. I want to know if there is a similar app for iPhone. Ideally it would also only use the local network. I do not want to send my data to some stranger. Preferably free and open-source.

Comment: Only one I know of is the Camera APP for OBS Studio BUT that's to a PC / Mac (and not cheap). An App called Livestream (livestream.com) has an API for the streaming service but that looks very expensive and is cloud based. Only home based chat service I can think of is NextCloud but I've no idea if you can built that for a Pi.